# Insert text+piped commands into file with sed

Tags: sed

I can't wrap my head around sed. I need to use it to insert the text "You have `n` files" into an existing file. I know that `ls | wc -l` gets me `n`, but for some reason I can't find the right syntax to get sed to insert that into an existing file below the first line.

Here is what I've come up with so far -

```
echo "File log for" `date` > filelog | sed -i '1s/You currently have `n` files /' filelog
```

My main issue (I hope) is getting sed to recognize the `ls | wc -l` along with the text as a single line.

Comment: unclear what you are asking... from what I can understand you need two commands, so change `|` to `;` or use the two commands separately.... to add something after a particular line, use the `a` command not substitute.. for ex: on GNU sed, ``sed -i '1aYou currently have `n` files' filelog`` .. no idea what you mean by n surrounded by backtick

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I put "n" in backticks just as a placeholder for a number (think algebra). I am getting the number from the ls | wc -l command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with `printf` and [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)

```
printf "File log for $(date)\nYou currently have $(ls | wc -l) files\n" > filelog
```

**Note:** [Avoid parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

For example, try adding a file with `touch $'\n'as` and count it. In this case though, we can use `-q` option to work around that

```
printf "File log for $(date)\nYou currently have $(ls -q | wc -l) files\n" > filelog
```

Comment: I finally gave up on sed and went with something very similar to this.

I'm marking this as the answer mainly because it is less complex than other examples, without losing any functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This miight work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '1e echo File log for $(date)' -e '1e echo You currently have $(ls|wc -l) files' file
```

Use the `e` command to evaluate the shell commands at the desired address.